# Please suggest ASP.Net source editor

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, web-controls

Can someone suggest an ASP.NET source code editor control that I can integrate into my web site?

Expected features:

1. Highlight ASP.NET source code, including server-side code, JavaScript, html, CSS
2. Intelligent suggesting  when typing the code (*a la* intellisense).
3. `Design View` is not required.

Comment: @George - I don't think that's a duplicate. The question you've suggested is about editors to use on the local PC. This question is about putting an editor into a web site.

Comment: @chrisF before he edited it 5 hours ago, it just said 'product'. It didn't say 'web site'.

Comment: @George - Sorry - I should have checked the edit history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a code editor which you can embed in your product try [Actipro Software](http://www.actiprosoftware.com/)'s Syntax Editor. It is packaged as a basic code editor which can be extended with .NET and Web language add-on packs. It is used in several excellent products including [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net).

- [Syntax Editor](http://www.actiprosoftware.com/Products/DotNet/WindowsForms/SyntaxEditor/Default.aspx)
- [.NET Languages Add-On](http://www.actiprosoftware.com/Products/DotNet/WindowsForms/SyntaxEditor/Addons/DotNet/Default.aspx)
- [Web Languages Add-On](http://www.actiprosoftware.com/Products/DotNet/WindowsForms/SyntaxEditor/Addons/Web/Default.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, I found the Codehighlighter, http://www.actiprosoftware.com/Products/DotNet/ASPNET/CodeHighlighter/Default.aspx

But it does not support editing

Comment: The code highlighter does not, no, but the software at the first link above (Syntax Editor) most certainly does allow editing.